# How to add Info Button in Tab Bar item.?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using a UiTabBar  in my iPhone application. I want to show the info(*i*) Button in third tab bar iTem.
Can any one help how can i info Button ?

Comment: how to plan to add programatically or using xib

Comment: `[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];` is info button type. but i'm not sure if this will work UITabBar button..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a new Tab Bar Item, and change the bar icon, on Bar item -> image. Like this You will have a button like the others...

If you don't want to have another Bar item, you can add a new subview with an info button (I did it once, and it works great). I only recommend this for iPad, because on iphone the Tab Bar Itens occupy all the tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you using xib- In that Tab Bar Item>>>Identifier>>>custom

Then insert your image of "i" and do your process for the button

Answer (score 0):

Just add the button on the UITabBar and in attribute inspector set its "Type" property as info.

For BarButtonItem you dont have the "Type" property hence you have to use a simple button.